# Slice ndarray with indexes defined in another ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following:

```py
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
idx = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])
```

Is there a way to "numpy-slice" the array such that I use the i-th row from `idx` as index for the i-th row from `a` i.e `a[i,idx[i]]`?

This can easily be done by a loop:

```py
np.vstack([a[i, idx[i]] for i in range(len(a))])
```

But I thought there must be a numpy way of doing it.

The end-result should be:

```py
[[1,3],
 [5,6]]
```

Doing `a[idx]` does not work. If I do `a[:,idx]` then I get too many results i.e that gives

```py
array([[[1, 3],
        [2, 3]],
       [[4, 6],
        [5, 6]]])
```

which is close, but not correct.

Comment: Your idx seems off, it has 2 in both directions, probably you want `[0, 1]` as the second part. You can then use a production of the two rows of idx to generate an array of row and column number and use that as `a[rows, columns]` to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to select the required indices along the `1` axis:

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(a, idx, 1)
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: For some reason it does not give the same result as `np.vstack([a[i, idx[i]] for i in range(len(a))])`

Comment: @CutePoison with the example you gave, both give the same result for me (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqKMP.png) Are you sure your example is representative of your actual arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy's [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to get your desired result.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
idx = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])
res = a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[[1 3]
 [5 6]]
```